# References Instrumental Variables

Tags: instrumental-variables

is anyone an well-informed about instrumental variable in economics ?

I'd like to have a list of good papers or books (i don't know how to identify them) such that f i read and understand completely all of them i'd be an expert of instrumental variables.

I already read (in deep) some papers : 
Angrist and Imbens (1994) : «Idenfification and Estimation of Local Average Treatment Effects »
Angrist and Imbens (1995) : « Two-stage Least Squares Estimation of Average Causal Effects in Models with Variable Treatment Intensity »
Angrist, Imbens and Rubin (1996) : « Identification of Causal Effects Using Instrumental Variables »
Alet et al. (2013) : « Repetition : Medicine for a Short-run remission »

Thanks, i'm available for further details if needed

Comment: Any econometrics textbook has a chapter on instrumental variables. From a more advanced perspective, the chapter by Newey and McFadden in the handbook of econometrics covers GMM in quite some detail, of which IV is a special case, see Newey, W.; McFadden, D. (1994). "Large sample estimation and hypothesis testing". Handbook of Econometrics. Elsevier Science. pp. 2111–2245. doi:10.1016/S1573-4412(05)80005-4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, It will be useful

Answer (score 1):

I think the best introductory text to instrumental variables is Chapter 4 in Mostly Harmless Econometrics. See https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/203124/mod_resource/content/1/Angrist%20%20Pischke.pdf.